# javascript translation, encode in php decode in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, decode, encode

Hi I'm trying to encode a string in PHP then output in javascript because otherwise Javascript gives me error.

I tried this http://pastebin.com/7RmjDcJY:

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function lang(translate){
    var translations = new Array();";
    foreach($languageTranslations AS $key=>$value):
        echo "translations[\"".$key."\"] = \"". base64_encode($value)."\";";
    endforeach;
   echo "return (typeof translations[translate]!='undefined') ? $.base64.decode(translations[translate]) : translate;

}
</script>";?>
```

But förnamn -> FÃ¶rnamn

Any idea? I've utf-8 in my document, but I guess bas64 can't convert utf-8 properly?

I can't just output the value, because some contains characters that breaks my javascript.

Or should I do a replace first? Like replace " with \" and stuff?

EDIT:

Now I got:

```
//urlencode in PHP and:
decodeURIComponent(translations[translate]).replace('+',' ')
```

But that doesn't feel like the right thing. What if I had an + sign in my text?

Answer (score 2):

for send data from php to JavaScript you can base64 data and if you have more than one data to send use json_encode for send multi  data,then in javaScript use json decode for get value and decode base64 by this code

```
   var Base64 = {

// private property
_keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

// public method for encoding
encode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

    while (i < input.length) {

        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
},

// public method for decoding
decode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    while (i < input.length) {

        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

    }

    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

    return output;

},

// private method for UTF-8 encoding
_utf8_encode : function (string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
    var utftext = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
        else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }

    }

    return utftext;
},

// private method for UTF-8 decoding
_utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

    while ( i < utftext.length ) {

        c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

        if (c < 128) {
            string += String.fromCharCode(c);
            i++;
        }
        else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
            i += 2;
        }
        else {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
            c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
            i += 3;
        }

    }

    return string;
}

}
```

sample:

```
  alert(Base64._utf8_decode(2LTYs9uM2YTYqNi02LPbjNio2YLYq9in24zYqNmE2LDYs9uM2KjYsQ==));
```

this code compatible with utf-8

Comment: if you copy someones code, at least leave a note: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html